# I need to retrieve only date from login1 field which is varchar having value like this 1/24/2019 13:22:22?

Tags: mysql

I'm have a table where I'm capturing login and logout time from front end application. The login and logout time is sitting in the database in this format 1/24/2019 13:22:22, now I need only date from it.

So that I can use to retrieve data based on the particular date i.e., I can use select statement with where clause giving the date and getting the data.

Can anyone help me in converting this. I'm using varchar field to store the input value coming from front end.

This is the table and based on the login1 field date i need to retrieve the data.

[image]

Comment: As it's working. What do you need from us?

Comment: I think I have confused you with answer. The format which was there in the query is different from which I need to convert. I have updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: See about data types

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to do the query required for getting the data as I needed

```
  SELECT * FROM timesheet where login1 LIKE '%1/24/2019%'
```

Comment: like is not a good idea for doing this as its decrease performance as well as strict you while filtering between two date

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select date(STR_TO_DATE(login1, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'))
```

Comment: This worked but i'm getting only the particular date which we pass. But I need to use the date to retrieve all the data on that particular date. Can you help me with that.

Comment: you need to add your column name, I've edited the answer - you can check

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast or convert as a VARCHAR datatype, you can try below query to get only the date.

```
SELECT CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00-08:00' as DATE) as DATE1 FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way also-

```
  select * FROM Login WHERE date_format(STR_TO_DATE(logindate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%m/%d/%Y') = date('01/18/2019')
```